# Python: How to merge 1 list of n dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this list:

I want to be able to group these dictionaries according to the department

```
departments = [
{
    "department": 4,
    "user": 1,
    "status": False
},
{
    "department": 2,
    "user": 1,
    "status": True
},
{
    "department": 2,
    "user": 2,
    "status": True
}]
```

I want this:

```
departments = [
{
    "department": 4,
    "user": 1,
    "status": False
},
{
    "department": 2,
    "user": [1, 2]
    "status": True
}]
```

How to do that?

Comment: you didn't even try man

Comment: Hello, Héctor, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at [help] and [ask]. Generally, a good question will show "research effort" (hover over the up-vote arrow). Usually, although not always, this involves some code that you've tried and failed to get to work, i.e. a [mcve]. Otherwise, you should show that you've at least tried to look for other SO questions but haven't been able to find an answer or the answers you've found have not been adequate - or you haven't been able to get them to work. I suggest editing your question with this in mind to help gain more traction.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import collections
new_data = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(departments, key=lambda x:x["department"])]
final_data = [{"department":a, 'status':list(set([i["status"] for i in b])), 'user':[i["user"] for i in b]} for a, b in new_data]
```

Output:

```
[{'department': 4, 'status': [False], 'user': [1]}, {'department': 2, 'status': [True], 'user': [1, 2]}]
```

This solution factors in the possibility of having multiple possibilities for values for each keys. Hence, each value for "status" and "user" is in a list.

Or, to perfectly match the OP's desired output:

```
final_data = [{"department":a, 'status':list(set([i["status"] for i in b]))[0] if len(set([i["status"] for i in b])) == 1 else list(set([i["status"] for i in b])), 'user':list(set([i["user"] for i in b]))[0] if len(set([i["user"] for i in b])) == 1 else list(set([i["user"] for i in b]))} for a, b in new_data]
```

Output:

```
[{'department': 4, 'status': False, 'user': 1}, {'department': 2, 'status': True, 'user': [1, 2]}]
```

Comment: Jeez, dude, a *310* character-long list-comprehension? Indents and for-loops never killed anybody